# Why am I getting an error with requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I usually write code on Pycharm at work using the mac but not that I am working from home I opened up Visual studio to try to automate some work. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

```
>>> r=requests.get(url,path,auth=auth)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 551, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

> > > 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an issue with your IDE. The call `r=requests.get(url,path,auth=auth)` doesn't look like a valid requests call.

- The "path" parameter doesn't exist
- It seems like you're passing as auth an **invalid** auth method.

You can't pass something like requests.get('url', auth='123123'), you need to specify the auth TYPE, as in:

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
requests.get(f'{url}/{path}', auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

This way you add the path to the url, and set a correct auth method (in this case, http basic auth).